# Acumatica API - Delete Sales Order Lines

Tags: api, line, acumatica, erp

I want to delete all sales order lines by given OrderNbr and then insert new sales order lines using the same Sales Order Number.
This will be done only for Sales order in 'Open' or 'Credit Hold' status and whenever the order line has not been shipped of course.

How can I get the lines row count and go through each one to delete then?
How can I use the SO301000.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.DeleteRow?

Comment: did you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use something like:

```html
var commands = new List<Command>
{
    new Value { LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderType, Value = "SO"},
    new Value { LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr, Value = "XXXXXX"},

    SO301000.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.RowNumber,
    SO301000.DocumentDetails.OrderType,
    SO301000.DocumentDetails.OrderNbr,
    SO301000.DocumentDetails.LineNbr,
    SO301000.DocumentDetails.InventoryID,
    SO301000.DocumentDetails.Quantity,
};

var content = context.SO301000Submit(commands.ToArray());
```

Then loop through "content" which is now a list of all the rows in your sales order and do a *SO301000.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.DeleteRow* to get rid of them.

Comment: Thanks Gavin, That is how it was done.
It is funny that we work for the same company. lol

Answer (score 1):

This also works with Quotes or any Marketing Document as well.

Below is the code for further reference:

```
try {
    apitest.Screen context = new apitest.Screen();
    context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();

    context.Url = "http://localhost/Acumatica52v1865/Soap/APITEST.asmx";

    LoginResult lresult = context.Login("admin", "123");

    var SO301000 = context.SO301000GetSchema();
    context.SO301000Clear();

    var commands = new List<Command>
    {
        new Value { LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderType, Value = "SO"},
        new Value { LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr, Value = "000179"},

        SO301000.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.RowNumber,
        SO301000.DocumentDetails.OrderType,
        SO301000.DocumentDetails.OrderNbr,
        SO301000.DocumentDetails.LineNbr,
        SO301000.DocumentDetails.InventoryID,
        SO301000.DocumentDetails.Quantity,
    };

    var content = context.SO301000Submit(commands.ToArray());

    List<Command> cmds = new List<Command>();
    cmds.Add(new Value { LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderType, Value = "SO" });
    cmds.Add(new Value { LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr, Value = "000179" });

    //Remove all row,
    foreach (var item in content)
    {
        cmds.AddRange(new List<Command>
                {
                    SO301000.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.DeleteRow
                });
    }

    cmds.Add(SO301000.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.NewRow);
    cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "301CMPST01", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.InventoryID, Commit = true });
    cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "2", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.Quantity, Commit = true });
    cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "110", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.UnitPrice });

    cmds.Add(SO301000.Actions.Save);
    context.SO301000Submit(cmds.ToArray());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```